# Is there a desktop mechanism similar to UWP windows.protocol?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

UWP apps can register for a custom scheme by using `Extension Category="windows.protocol"` ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-protocol)).  I'm aware of custom protocol handlers by registering a URI scheme ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx)) but those always launch a new instance of the app.  What I want is the behavior of a UWP app:  if there is a currently running instance, it gets activated.

I also looked into URL Monikers and Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774965(v=vs.85).aspx)) but those only work when invoking the protocol in-process, such as when using a Web view.  A UWP app gets activated even if some other process, such as a Web browser, invokes the protocol.

This is for a C++ Win32 desktop application; .NET is not an option.

Also, as I said in my comment to Anders's proposal, I don't want to have to create a separate component to activate my running app when some other process, such as a browser, invokes my protocol.  UWP apps have no such requirement and I want the same for my app.

Comment: It would help clarify your question, if you removed the UWP references, and instead succinctly posted the requirements you are after.

Comment: The standard way to do this is to have the application check for an existing instance during startup and if there is one pass a request to the old instance and terminate. Everybody does that, not only in regard to protocol handlers. There's no problem with doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [`IExecuteCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378382), that is what Internet Explorer does for its HTTP registration (DelegateExecute). Your implementation can simply look for and communicate with a existing instance of your application (if there is one) or launch normally.

[This blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100312-01/?p=14623/) should get you started...

Comment: I think this is no better than registering a custom protocol handler since it also requires a separate component, a COM component, that executes in a separate process, the shell. UWP apps don't require any additional components.

Comment: An out-of-proc COM server executes in your application but yes, it is extra work to do it this way.

Comment: @Anders: I always thought that "out-of-proc" stands for "out of *process*". Does it not? Or do you use a broad definition of "application" that includes multiple processes?

Comment: It will create multiple processes when some other process invokes your protocol but that is unavoidable (except the first time when your app is not running). It will not however run in the shell, it will run in another instance of your applications .exe when it is out-of-proc.